# statsmodel package grangercausalitytests output explanation?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statistics, time-series, statsmodels

I'm currently doing a project where I'm trying to find evidence of causality between human activity and global warming. I've been trying to run a granger causality test of annual emissions on global temperature after differencing both variables and checking for unit roots.

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'temp':temperature,'emissions':emissions)
sm.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests(test,30)
```

Can somebody help me make more sense of the output given?

Sample Output for Lag 11 and 14:

```
Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 11
ssr based F test:         F=1.1019  , p=0.3716  , df_denom=76, df_num=11
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=15.7887 , p=0.1492  , df=11
likelihood ratio test: chi2=14.6493 , p=0.1991  , df=11
parameter F test:         F=1.1019  , p=0.3716  , df_denom=76, df_num=11

...
number of lags (no zero) 14
ssr based F test:         F=1.2862  , p=0.2394  , df_denom=67, df_num=14
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=25.8004 , p=0.0274  , df=14
likelihood ratio test: chi2=22.8514 , p=0.0627  , df=14
parameter F test:         F=1.2862  , p=0.2394  , df_denom=67, df_num=14
```

When would the Chi-squared test results be preferable to the F test? I was under the impression that Chi-squared is preferred with higher lag number, but the original sample size is pretty small ( n = 100).

If the null hypothesis of the test is no granger causality, I'm guessing that there under the chi-squared test, emissions 'granger causes' global warming at a 95% CI at lag 14? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: maybe ask on stats.stackexchange for a statistical explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The evidence for Granger causality is pretty weak.

The sample size is small and the chi2 Wald tests based on the asymptotic distribution might over reject. Using F distribution has in many cases better small sample properties, but I don't know whether this is also the case for Granger causality tests, i.e. a Wald test in a vector autoregressive setting.

Also, if we try several different lags, then we also run into multiple testing problems. If you run many tests, then you might find one purely randomly that is significant if the p-values are not corrected for multiple testing.